# Cleaner Way To Write This Multiple SQL Statement

Tags: sql, select, join, merge

I'm looking for a cleaner way to write these sql statements. I'm basically wanting to pull data from table 1 and sort it based on the results of table 2. The second sql statement is based on the condition of the first.  I have tried join but did not have any success with it.

Here's what I have working at the moment:

```
    $sql= "SELECT * FROM yt_Business_RegInfo WHERE deleted = '0' ORDER BY companyName ASC";

    //Execute SQL statement
    if(!($result = mysql_query($sql)))
    die("Error in executing query");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $busID = $row['id'];
    $companyName = $row["companyName"];
    $membershipID = $row['membershipID'];


    $sql2= "SELECT * FROM yt_Business_Membership WHERE id = '$membershipID' AND approved = 1";

    //Execute SQL statement
    if(!($result2 = mysql_query($sql2)))
    die("Error in executing query");
   //Retrieve values
   while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) { 

    echo $companyName; 

     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL statements can be combined into a single one with inner join like this

```
SELECT * FROM yt_Business_RegInfo R
INNER JOIN yt_Business_Membership M
    ON R.membershipID = M.ID AND R.approved = 1
WHERE R.deleted = '0'
ORDER BY R.companyName ASC
```

Comment: Thanks, I just had to change the R.approved to M.approved. Now since I have duplicate field names for id I changed my SELECT * to R.id,companyName,membershipID.  Works well.